# How do I make the Windmill IDE appear for https sites on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, https, windmill

I am trying to use the Windmill Testing Framework over https. I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with Python 2.7, installing `windmill` and `pyopenssl` in a virtualenv via pip. (Installation sequence is included below for reference.)

When I run `windmill firefox http://en.wikipedia.org` the Windmill IDE comes up fine. When I run `windmill firefox https://en.wikipedia.org` Firefox starts, but the IDE never appears. (I have verified that [when Windmill starts Firefox on Ubuntu, the CA for https is already installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94269/how-do-i-install-a-crt-file-in-firefox-for-windmill-testing-framework).)

Am I encountering a bug, or is there something else I need to do to get the IDE to work on https addresses?

**Installation sequence**

```
myuser@mycomputer:~$ mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages windmill_test
New python executable in windmill_test/bin/python
Installing distribute....................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip...............done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/windmill_test/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/windmill_test/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/windmill_test/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/windmill_test/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/windmill_test/bin/get_env_details
(windmill_test)myuser@mycomputer:~$ pip install pyopenssl
Downloading/unpacking pyopenssl
  Downloading pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz (250Kb): 250Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyopenssl

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: pyopenssl
  Running setup.py install for pyopenssl
    building 'OpenSSL.crypto' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/x509.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/x509.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/x509name.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/x509name.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/pkey.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/pkey.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/x509store.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/x509store.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/x509req.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/x509req.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/x509ext.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/x509ext.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/pkcs7.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/pkcs7.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/pkcs12.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/pkcs12.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/netscape_spki.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/netscape_spki.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/revoked.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/revoked.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/crypto/crl.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/crl.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/util.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/util.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/x509.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/x509name.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/pkey.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/x509store.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/x509req.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/x509ext.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/pkcs7.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/pkcs12.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/netscape_spki.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/revoked.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto/crl.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/util.o -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/crypto.so
    building 'OpenSSL.rand' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/rand/rand.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/rand/rand.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/util.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/util.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/rand/rand.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/util.o -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/rand.so
    building 'OpenSSL.SSL' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/ssl/connection.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/ssl/context.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/ssl/context.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/ssl/ssl.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/ssl/ssl.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c OpenSSL/util.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/util.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/ssl/connection.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/ssl/context.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/ssl/ssl.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/util.o -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/OpenSSL/SSL.so

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
Successfully installed pyopenssl
Cleaning up...
(windmill_test)myuser@mycomputer:~$ pip install windmill
Downloading/unpacking windmill
  Downloading windmill-1.6.tar.gz (1.6Mb): 1.6Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package windmill

Installing collected packages: windmill
  Running setup.py install for windmill

    Installing windmill script to /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/windmill_test/bin
Successfully installed windmill
Cleaning up...
(windmill_test)myuser@mycomputer:~$ pip freeze
distribute==0.6.19
pyOpenSSL==0.13
windmill==1.6
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

**http**

```
(windmill_test)myuser@mycomputer:~$ windmill firefox http://en.wikipedia.org
windmill.bin.shell_objects: INFO     ['/home/myuser/.mozilla/firefox/p3t9ijqj.mozrunner//mozrunner-firefox', '-profile', '/home/myuser/.mozilla/firefox/p3t9ijqj.mozrunner/', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/windmill-serv/start.html']
```

Attempts to load http://en.wikipedia.org/windmill-serv/start.html but resolves to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page . IDE loads.

**https**

```
(windmill_test)myuser@mycomputer:~$ windmill firefox https://en.wikipedia.org
windmill.bin.shell_objects: INFO     ['/home/myuser/.mozilla/firefox/p3t9ijqj.mozrunner//mozrunner-firefox', '-profile', '/home/myuser/.mozilla/firefox/p3t9ijqj.mozrunner/', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/windmill-serv/start.html']
```

Attempts to load https://en.wikipedia.org/windmill-serv/start.html and resolves to that pages (which displays a 404 page, which then redirects to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windmill-serv/start.html - I'm just using Wikipedia as an example here, so it doesn't matter that it returns 404s or "Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name"). The IDE never loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, this was a user error :D

I was running `windmill firefox https://www.example.com` instead of `windmill firefox https://www.example.com ssl`